# JPA Many to Two relationship

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

I'm new to JPA and was wondering if JPA contains a solution for my problem. Els I will just need to create a ManyToMany relationship.

My application contains roads and camera's. A road starts and ends with a camera. I created this by creating a property `cameraPointA` and `cameraPointB` in the `RoadSegment` class. This created a many to two relationship. I thought I could define this as two many to one relationships but this seems not possible.

`CameraPoint.java`

```
@Entity
public class CameraPoint implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "cameraPointA or cameraPointA") //<== The Problem
    private List<RoadSegment> roads;

    //...
}
```

`RoadSegment.java`

```
@Entity
public class RoadSegment implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Region region;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private CameraPoint cameraPointA;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private CameraPoint cameraPointB;

    //...
}
```

Comment: How about two fields, `one mappedBy = "cameraPointA"`, one `mappedBy = "cameraPointB"`, plus some getter which combines those two fields? EDIT: Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2181003/3890673)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work but maybe you can try adding to `CameraPoint` another list of `RoadSegments`, which indicate the Camera has a list of roads where the camera is the start and the other list indicates the camera is the last.

```
@Entity
public class CameraPoint implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private long id;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "cameraPointA")
private List<RoadSegment> roadsA;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "cameraPointB")
private List<RoadSegment> roadsB;

//...
}
```

Is really necessary to use bidirectional relationship ? Maybe it is not and your model would be more easy.

For example, if you always reach to the `CameraPoint` from a `RoadSegment` then you don't need the `@OneToMany` relationship on `CameraPoint`.

The same applies for the inverse mode, if you always get a `RoadSegment` from a previous `CameraPoint`, then the `@ManyToOne` relationship is not necessary.